# How to change location of .activator .sbt .ivy folders in Play 2.3?

Tags: playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator, playframework-2.3

I have just started learning Play Framework 2.3.0 and am trying to move

- `.activator`
- `.sbt`
- `.ivy`

folders from `%USERPROFILE%` folder to a custom folder like `C:/learning/playframework/` on my Windows 7 machine. I want them to be portable / not lost during a OS re install.

I modified the `sbt.boot.properties` and changed the `user.home` to the custom location and passed `play.home` to `activator.bat` as a parameter.

Although `.sbt` and `.ivy` folders are initially created in the custom folder, when I try to create a new application `HelloWorld` all these folders again get created in the user directory `%USERPROFILE%` and all the files are downloaded there. The `.activator` never gets created in the custom folder and is always created in the `%USERPROFILE%` folder.

I also made sure there were no spaces in the paths.

**sbt.boot.properties:**

```
[app]
  org: com.typesafe.activator
  name: activator-launcher
  version: ${activator.version-read(activator.version)[1.2.1]}
  class: activator.ActivatorLauncher
  cross-versioned: false
  components: xsbti

[repositories]
  local
  activator-local: file://${activator.local.repository-${activator.home-${play.home}/.activator}/repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central
  typesafe-releases: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases
  typesafe-ivy-releasez: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]

[boot]
 directory: ${sbt.boot.directory-${sbt.global.base-${play.home}/.sbt}/boot/}
 properties: ${activator.boot.properties-${play.home}/.activator/version-${activator.launcher.generation-0}.properties}

[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${play.home}/.ivy2
  checksums: ${sbt.checksums-sha1,md5}
  override-build-repos: ${sbt.override.build.repos-false}
  repository-config: ${sbt.repository.config-${sbt.global.base-${play.home}/.sbt}/repositories}
```

Please advise on configuring the Activator/Play Framework such that - the 3 directories and the repository get created in a custom directory, say `C:/learning/playframework/`.

Comment: How do you *"passed play.home to activator.bat as a parameter."*?

Answer (score 5):

> The .activator never gets created in the custom folder and is always
>   created in the %USERPROFILE% folder.

My understanding is that `~/.activator` is controlled by the startup script where you should be able to point to a custom directory.

For `~/.sbt` you should really be using `sbt.global.base` property as I see it used in the sbt code itself.

If you want to see under the hood, you could query for the current values of the home directories for sbt and Ivy with `consoleProject` command (it assumes you started `activator` with `activator -Dsbt.global.base=./sbt -Dsbt.ivy.home=./ivy2`):

```
> consoleProject
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
import sbt._
import Keys._
import _root_.sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.CorePlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
import currentState._
import extracted._
import cpHelpers._
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_60).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> appConfiguration.eval.provider.scalaProvider.launcher.bootDirectory
res0: java.io.File = /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-launcher/minimal-scala/sbt/boot

scala> appConfiguration.eval.provider.scalaProvider.launcher.ivyHome
res1: java.io.File = /Users/jacek/.ivy2
```

*Iff* you're really into convincing Activator to use `sbt.ivy.home`, you have to change `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` in `activator-launch-1.2.2.jar`. Just follow the steps:

1. Unpack `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` out of `activator-launch-1.2.2.jar`.

   ```
   jar -xvf activator-launch-1.2.2.jar sbt/sbt.boot.properties
   ```
2. Edit `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` and replace `ivy-home` under `[ivy]`.

   ```
   ivy-home: ${sbt.ivy.home-${user.home}/.ivy2}
   ```
3. Add the changed `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` to `activator-launch-1.2.2.jar`.

   ```
   jar -uvf activator-launch-1.2.2.jar sbt/sbt.boot.properties
   ```

With the change, `-Dsbt.ivy.home=./ivy2` works fine.

```
scala> appConfiguration.eval.provider.scalaProvider.launcher.bootDirectory
res0: java.io.File = /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-launcher/minimal-scala/sbt/boot

scala> appConfiguration.eval.provider.scalaProvider.launcher.ivyHome
res1: java.io.File = /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-launcher/minimal-scala/ivy2
```

Comment: Where is the startup script in reference to the `~/.activator` folder? I have tried changing `activator.bat` etc but it is still created in the `%USERPROFILE%` folder. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `activatorconfig.txt` file `%USERPROFILE%/.activator/` 
In this file, place the following content :

```
-Dactivator.local.repository=C:\learning\playframework\repository
-Dactivator.home=C:\learning\playframework\
-Dsbt.ivy.home=C:\learning\playframework\repository
-Duser.home=C:\learning\playframework\
-Divy-home=C:\learning\playframework\repository
```